How to rectify this mismatch error in the case of Neural Surrogates BatchNormalization
x_train = 
100-element Vector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}:
 (0.1875, 3.1875)
 (4.1875, 7.1875)
 (6.1875, 1.1875)
 (2.1875, 5.1875)
 (3.1875, 0.1875)
 (7.1875, 4.1875)
 (5.1875, 2.1875)
 (1.1875, 6.1875)
 (1.6875, 1.6875)
 (5.6875, 5.6875)
 ⋮
 (3.34375, 5.90625)
 (2.34375, 0.90625)
 (6.34375, 4.90625)
 (4.34375, 2.90625)
 (0.34375, 6.90625)
 (0.46875, 0.53125)
 (4.46875, 4.53125)
 (6.46875, 2.53125)
 (2.46875, 6.53125)

y_train = 
100-element Vector{Float64}:
 10.1953125
 69.1953125
 39.6953125
 31.6953125
 10.1953125
 69.1953125
 31.6953125
 39.6953125
  5.6953125
 64.6953125
  ⋮
 46.064453125
  6.314453125
 64.314453125
 27.314453125
 47.814453125
  0.501953125
 40.501953125
 48.251953125
 48.751953125

# Define the neural network model with normalization
model1 = Chain(
    Dense(2, 100),
    BatchNorm(10, relu),
    Dense(10, 10),
    BatchNorm(10),
    Dense(10, 1)
)


neural_surrogate = NeuralSurrogate(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    lower_bound,
    upper_bound,
    model = model1,
    n_echos = 10
)

Error:
layer BatchNorm(10, relu) expects ndims(input) > 1, but got 100-element Vector{Float32}
Tried changing the dimesnions of the Dense and the Batch Norm, but always ended up with some other error.
Actually I dont understand the Neural Networks topic well in Julia, and thus need assistance for the sa

Could you please add the library imports to you code as well so that others can reproduce easily?

Also x_train is truncated in between, which is another obstacle for repro.
